# How to share files between two Ubuntu 14.04 computers

Tags: networking, samba, shared-folders

I've trying to share files between my two computers by WIFI and SAMBA. I checked share option in folder properties and tried to connect to other computer by smb://ip. But without succes.
Could some one hep me how to do this step by step. Maybe I did something wrong...

Answer (score 2):

I was able to share between two Ubuntu 14.04 computers.  I checked the share option on the appropriate folder on one computer.  Then on the other computer I used Files --> Network --> Connect to Server and entered the server address as smb://ip.  Is this exactly what you tried?